# Graduate Degree Question

Tags: discussion

I'm currently about halfway through an engineering Master's degree program. Pretty soon I need to decide whether to choose a thesis option or just take more electives. I'd like to ask this question to this site, but I'm not sure if it's appropriate. The education tag is as follows:

> Use this tag for questions about engineering education, including but not limited to curriculum, accreditation programs, mentoring programs and educational internships. Do not request individual academic guidance.

While the question could certain qualify as individual academic guidance, if I ask it to draw more general answers, would it be appropriate? Should I include details about my education to get detailed responses or leave it very generic to ensure generic answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> While the question could certain qualify as individual academic guidance, if I ask it to draw more general answers, would it be appropriate?

Likely not. Academic guidance is inherently specific to a particular student at a particular institution; [that's one of the main reasons we don't provide it here.](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/are-academic-guidance-questions-on-topic) You can't generalize such a question without making it much less useful to real individuals, and that's a bad sign for a site that focuses on solving real, practical problems *shared among* many individual readers.

> Should I include details about my education to get detailed responses or leave it very generic to ensure generic answers?

I can't reasonably advise you on how to write questions that are off-topic for this site. What I can do is point you to [another site on the network where your question might be better received](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you'd like to attract the attention of our user base to your question, feel free to drop a link in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=engineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I figured this would be the answer which is why I wanted to post in the Meta first. One of my professors gave me a stock answer in favor of the thesis option, so I was curious if a standard answer existed from a community with different biases. Thanks!